# What are good regular expressions ONLY for /* ... */ block?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

What are good regular expressions using `NSRegularExpression` for /* ... */ block like that?

```
code /* bla-bla-bla
bla-bla-bla // embedded comment */ code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that may give you better result for multiple lines comments, but it does not work with embedded comment-blocks. (the single line embedded comments are okay inside the block).

```
(/\*[\s\S]*?\*/)
```

## update

it catches all comment blocks and single line comment as well, but it still not working with embedded comment-blocks.

```
^(/\*[\s\S]*?\*/)$|^(\/\/.*?\n?)$
```

Comment: How can I add support for embedded comment and string blocks?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover all cases.

Comment: the first sceario with the single line `// embedded comment` is okay for this regexp. in the case of second one it stops when it finds the first `*/`.

Comment: It's ok, but I should have the correct regexp for // and for strings too...

Comment: holex, why do you use `(/\*[\s\S]*?\*/)` instead `(/\*.*?\*/)`?

Comment: @Altaveron, it is only a bad-habit. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I've posted updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168145/what-are-the-correct-regular-expressions-using-nsregularexpression-for-comments

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this for a project, have a look at https://github.com/wader/respect/blob/master/Respect/TextFile.m#L47

A special case is to handle comments inside quoted strings, e.g. `"/* not a comment */"`, which is a bit tricky. I solve this by capturing them first and skip them.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works incorrectly.

Comment: Ok but how does it work incorrectly? it works fine to strip out comments in source code in project i linked too. What do you want to do? get the text inside all comments?

Comment: For example, it works incorrectly with the following string: `code // comment "comment"` I've checked exactly your regexp with it.

Comment: You can find full test on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168145/what-are-the-correct-regular-expressions-using-nsregularexpression-for-comments