# What are the correct regular expressions for syntax highlighting?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

What are the correct regular expressions using NSRegularExpression for syntax highlighting?

The following test must be passed:

```
code // comment
code /* comment */ code
code "string" code

code // comment
  code
code /* comment
  comment */ code
code "string
  code" string
code "string\
  string" code

code // comment "comment"
code /* comment "comment" */ code
code "string /* string */ // string" code

code // comment
  "string"
code /* comment
  "comment" */ code
code "string
  /* comment */ // comment" string
code "string\
  /* string */ // string" code

code // comment // comment
code /* comment /* comment */ code */
code "string \" string" code "string" code
```

Comment: this situation `/* comment /* comment */ code */` might be resolved by an quite complex regular expression.

Comment: I suggest that you provide test strings and the desired result. test01 = @"// comment" check01 = @"comment" for unambiguous verification. The current question is ambiguous in what the result of `code // comment "comment"` should return.

Comment: @zx81, you should post that as an answer so I can downvote it.  :D    But seriously, there's *nothing* straightforward about this task.  It may not require a full-on parser, but it can't be done with regexes alone.  Also, the quoted-string regex in your comment is an abomination, and you should get a ruling on whether block comments can be nested (in most languages they can't).

Comment: Oh, and NSRegularExpression is powered by [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), which does not support recursive patterns or anything similar.

Comment: @Alan Swift supports nested comments and it is "the future".

Comment: @AlanMoore Wow, good morning! Yeah you're right that was an abomination, that will teach me trying to write a comment at 4am on my way to the loo! lol `(?<=")(?:\\"|[^"])*` is more like it. Took down the original for that reason, but it did say `I don't know nsregularexpression, but`... so the other thoughts were just nudges. I know you disagree with "straighforward" but I'll paste it verbatim in case anything inspires Altaveron "The // comments are straightforward //.*. The /* ../*... */ comments are easily feasible in flavors that support recursion (?R) or balancing groups in .NET"

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you did those edits, but please don't do that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible in global sense (not just on the sample). So, regexp cann't be used for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Using PCRE, the (?s) modifier is a single-line mode, where `.` can even match newlines.

```
(?ms)(//[^\n]+|/\*.*?\*/)
```

[Live example](http://regex101.com/r/eB9bE4)

You will notice that the second-to-last line, with nested `/* /*  */ */` will ONLY match the first `/*` to the first `*/`, and will not match the `*/` at the end of the line (which is actually correct behavior).

Comment: WRT the second-to-last line Swift supports nested comments.

Comment: PCRE is not Obj-C regexp.